# Errors compile OpenCV (C++) on Debian

Tags: c++, opencv

```
[  9%] Built target libwebp
[ 15%] Built target IlmImf
[ 17%] Built target ippiw
[ 23%] Built target libprotobuf
[ 24%] Built target quirc
[ 24%] Built target ittnotify
[ 24%] Built target opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp
[ 24%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[ 24%] Built target opencv_ts_pch_dephelp
[ 24%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ts
[ 24%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
make[2]: Warning: File '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so' has modification time 2220 s in the future
[ 24%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.so
make[2]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
[ 31%] Built target opencv_core
[ 31%] Built target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 31%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
[ 31%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so
[ 37%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 37%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp
[ 37%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgcodecs
make[2]: Warning: File '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so' has modification time 2217 s in the future
[ 37%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
make[2]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
[ 39%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 39%] Built target opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp
[ 39%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_videoio
[ 39%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vc1dsp_mmx.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_pw_9' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:231: lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3712: modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

When I try to compile OpenCV using command"make" ,it always has these errors.I have try OpenCV 3.4.5 4.0.1.And I have installed all the library that OpenCV needs .

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your current date & time

- It is abnormal to have messages like `Warning: File '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so' has modification time 2220 s in the future` concerning standard libs
- As you can see through the message *"warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete."* you disturb *make*, that one uses the date&time to recompile or not (even in your case probably all as to be compiled because there is no object/lib already done)

So you *really* need to update the date&time on your OS, activate *ntp*.

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vc1dsp_mmx.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_pw_9' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC"

the Makefiles are produced through *configure* to have the right compiler options, it seens you need to modify *configure.in* to add `-fPIC`

Difficult to say more because you did not even indicate your linux/other OS distribution ...